# Wikitude SDK remove from superview

Tags: iphone, view, augmented-reality, wikitude

I have implement Wikitude SDK and I manage to initialize using this code:

```
-(IBAction)launchAR:(id)sender{
        wikitudeAR = [[WikitudeARViewController alloc] initWithDelegate:self applicationPackage:nil applicationKey:nil applicationName:nil developerName:nil];  
}

- (void) verificationDidSucceed {

    BuddyFinderAppDelegate *appDel = (BuddyFinderAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    [appDel.window addSubview: [wikitudeAR start]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
}
```

How I will go back to my MainViewController View?
(I want to call it from object "custombutton")

Comment: This is works but then If i press any button in my mainviewcontroller is crashing!BuddyFinderAppDelegate *appDel = (BuddyFinderAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    
    MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [appDel.window addSubview:mvc.view];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use CustomMenuButtonDelegateImpl1.m

```
@implementation CustomMenuButtonDelegateImpl1

- (void) customMenuButtonPressed:(WTPoi *)currentSelectedPoi {
    //NSLog(@"addpoi");



    [[WikitudeARViewController sharedInstance] hide];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = NO;

    }


@end
```

and it woroks very well

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `WikitudeARViewController` delegate is application delegate.

1) Implement your own View controller , from where you want to launch AR Browser (on button click , preferably).

2) Instantiate WikitudeARViewController from your ViewController(button event) and making ViewController as delegate.

3) make view returned from [wikitudeAR start] to the ViewController.view (and not window.view).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello thanks for replying. So you saying that I have to write another view controller and do there the launch of the wikitudeAR? This would be difficult because I need wikitude in my main view controller(to pass data for initialization)

Comment: instead of `[appDel.window addSubview: [wikitudeAR start]];` , try [mvc.view addSubView:[wikitudeAR start]];` ?

Comment: I get warning: method -addsubview not found(return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: my bad, its a typo: [mvc.view addSubview:[wikitudeAR start]];`